# Facebook-like-like functionality in Joomla 1.7-2.5

Tags: facebook, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I'm looking for an extension that brings facebook-model ranking to Joomla. Precisely, i want to allow users to "like" or "+1" an article internally on a website i'm currently working on, not on fb or g+. Are there any well-known exts or hacks for something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the built-in content voting system you can enable it in several ways:

1. Article Manager -> Options -> Articles -> Show Voting (to enable globally)
2. Per Menu Item -> Article Options -> Show Voting (for articles under that menu item)
3. Per Article  -> Article Options -> Show Voting (for that specific article)

If that doesn't meet you needs have a look at the [Joomla! Extensions Directory (JED)](http://extensions.joomla.org) - I'd start with the "[Ratings & Reviews](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/ratings-a-reviews)" section. There are a range of options available some that integrate with social site or with social extensions like [JomSocial](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communities-a-groupware/communities/7608), Community Builder etc as well as stand-alone systems.

It's worth noting that larger extensions like [JomSocial have their own extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/jomsocial-extensions) on the JED that can include additional content "liking" and "rating" systems.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

[JV Facebook](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-display/facebook-display/14625)